# Disecting a string to execute a Class/Method with Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have been trying to figure this out and just can't seem to get it down right. It's really been bugging me and I really need help.

The bug I'm trying to fix resides in a little snippet of code I wrote in C# that it's mission is to disect a string (I'll give examples below) and create instances of a class and invoke a method with arguments (if any were supplied in the string), then to return the output respectively.

This is my code:

```
responseData = responseData.Trim(); // To eliminate annoying things in the string
string[] class_method = responseData.Split(new[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Type type = Type.GetType("paper." + class_method[0]);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

if (type != null)
{
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(class_method[1]);

    if (method != null)
    {
        foreach (string str in responseData.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Arg: " + str); // should output something like "Socket::ListenPort TCP 9000"
        }
        output = Toolkit.byteCode(method.Invoke(instance, null).ToString() + "\n");
    }
}
```

This is what is supposed to happen:

I will submit a string to this method that will look something like this:
`Socket::PortListener TCP 9000`. What I'm aiming for in the code is to take the first string before the '**::**' (Socket); it will create an instance of the class "**Socket**". Then it will take the string after the '**::**', so "**PortListener**" and execute that method. Afterwards, the code is supposed to grab the remaining arguments in the string "**TCP 9000**", and use those as arguments to invoke the method with.

An example of the `Socket::PortListener` class to accept these arguments is:

```
public void PortListener(string type_, int port)
{
    return type_ + port;
}
```

That's just an example. But the idea is that it will return the output like so based on the arguments supplied.

*note* I know that it has **null** where the argument array is supposed to go. That is just for testing reasons I needed to see that it gets the arguments correctly and prints them out to the screen before I change it to execute the method with the arguments. Please change that in advance when you come up with a fix.

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need more info or explanation on how the code is supposed to work. I am still fairly new to C# so I'm not very advanced in this area. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first view I see one problem:

If you have:

```
var responseData = "Socket::PortListener TCP 9000";
```

This will return you array with 2 strings in it:

```
string[] class_method = responseData.Split(new[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

1. Socket
2. PortListener TCP 9000

So this line will not work properly because in class_method[1] you have **PortListener TCP 9000**

```
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(class_method[1]);//this will be null
```

You need to split `class_method[1]` by `" "`

```
var methodData = class_method[1].Split(new char[0]);
```

So in the end your code will look like this:

```
if (type != null)
{
    var methodData = class_method[1].Split(new char[0]);
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodData[0]);

    if (method != null)
    {
        for(int i=1; i< methodData.Length; i++)
        {
            string str = methodData[i];
            System.Console.WriteLine("Arg: " + str); // should output something like "Socket::ListenPort TCP 9000"
        }
        output = Toolkit.byteCode(method.Invoke(instance, null).ToString() + "\n");
    }
}
```

**Just one tip: Use debug in the future, to avoid problems like this.**

Comment: Thanks! This worked and thanks for the explanation as to why it wasn't working as well. +1